# Collision detection not working

Tags: c#, collision-detection, xna-4.0

I made a collision detection in the Update() section, and this is the code:

```
            if (player.playerRect.Intersects(turtleRect))
        {
            turtleRect.X = turtleRect.X - 60;
        }
```

When I run the game, and collide with the turtle, nothing happens. I tried changing the

```
turtleRect.X = turtleRect.X - 60;
```

To

```
turtleRect.X = turtleRect.X - 600;
```

Because I thought I wasn't noticing the change. Still, nothing happened. Then I thought it was just the

```
turtleRect.X = turtleRect.X - 600
```

So I put that in the Update() method, outside of the if statement and it worked. Now I realize that it is the

```
                if (player.playerRect.Intersects(turtleRect))
        {

        }
```

But I cannot figure out what is wrong with that. I have the playerRect in a different class, but I imported it into the main class. I know the Rectangles are moving because of the

```
            turtleRect.X -= 1;
```

in the Update() method.
The turtle moves across the screen. I have tested many things, and looked it up and I still can't figure it out. This is the rectangle collision, so could somebody also guide me on how to do the per pixel collision? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: CJ if you want to indictate that you've figured this out. Add an answer below and mark it as such. Putting **Solved** is not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, I just added:

```
playerRect = new Rectangle((int)player.position.X, (int)player.position.Y, player.playerRect.Width, player.playerRect.Height);
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information than that, it could be that you aren't updating the coords after the collision or a million other things. Have you used the debugger to step through the application to determine what is happening after the collision? Secondly:

```
if (playerRect.Intersects(turtleRect))
{
   turtleRect.X = turtleRect.X - 60;
}
```

This is not collision resolution, it will only have a partially successful effect if the collision comes from the left on the X-axis you need to look into something more robust. The XNA platformer starter kit has fairly comprehensive collision detection this could be a good place to start.

Comment: What information do you need? I can post the whole class, or any specific part.